# java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException in org.xerial.snappy. While decompressing large file

Tags: java, compression, large-files, snappy

I got this error while I tried to decompress a large file using SnappyInputStream.
Size of sample.snappy is 10 GB. Is there a way around it?

I am using this https://github.com/xerial/snappy-java to compress and decompress snappy files.

Code source : Source

```
String fileName = "sample.snappy";
SnappyInputStream sis = new SnappyInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int len = 0;
while ((len = sis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    System.out.println(new String(buffer, 0, len));
}
```

Error Log:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
        at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyInputStream.readFully(SnappyInputStream.java:116)
        at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyInputStream.readHeader(SnappyInputStream.java:88)
        at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyInputStream.<init>(SnappyInputStream.java:58)
```

Line 116:

```
        byte[] newBuf = new byte[(compressed.length * 2)];
```

compressed is a byte array.

I assume `compressed.length*2` is larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` that is rolling over to negative number.

Comment: Try to debug your code to see if your assumption is correct. If it's overflow, use Long and/or check the size. Or perhaps compressed is -1 in case the file doesn't exist?

Comment: @JensvanGroeningen Array size can only be Integer. Better way to put it is Array max size should be less than 2^31 -1.

Comment: @OndraK. I will try that

Comment: @OndraK. I confirm that file size is is causing Integer val to roll over. 
File does exist.
I got file length. File length is -1175737566.